# Cleanup Code within JetBrains Resharper

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resharper, code-cleanup

I have two solutions within VS2012, one a branch of the other.

I have installed the latest version of resharper (8.0.2).

I open the same .cs file from both solutions.

On the one I get the warning triangle saying that I have unused directives, (which I do).  On the other I get no warnings or errors.  I have also noticed that the cleanup code feature within the one solution is disabled.

How can I enable this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resetting your Resharper options back to their defaults.

Resharper -> Manage Options -> Reset all settings

If that fixes the problem then I guess you've turned something off along the way.